# Stereo Microphone (BeyerDynamic MCE72)

Tags: stereo, microphone, review, experiences

Hi,

Just wanted to know if anyone had any reviews or experiences with using the BeyerDynamic MCE72 stereo mic? How does it compare with other stereo mics?

Thanks.